# Cannot implicitly convert IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario where I need to filter the query if date is given.

I have created a filter extension.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Between(this IQueryable<T> qry,
                                       DateTime start,
                                        DateTime end) 
{
  return from i in qry
         where i.Date >= start &&
               i.Date <= end
         select i;
}
```

In my controller.

```
public ActionResult Detail(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
  var foo = _db.Foo
             .Include("Bars")
             .Include("FoxItem.Fox")
             .Where(f => f.IsGood);

  if (start != null && end != null) {
    foo = foo
           .Between(start, end)
           .Select(f => new FooVm {
             FooId = f.Id,
             FooName = f.Name
           });
    return PartialView(foo);
  }

  foo = foo
        .Select(f => new FooVm {
             FooId = f.Id,
             FooName = f.Name
         });

  return View (foo);
}
```

And I am getting this error, it says:

**`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<FooVm> to System.Linq.IQueryable<Foo>'`**

What am I missing? Or what should be done to achieve the filter? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `var foo` is of the type `IQueryable<Foo>`. When you apply the Between and select of new `FooVm` you cannot cast this implicit to Foo. The return type of the Select will result in a `IQueryable<FooVm>` So you need to use a new variable. For e.q.

```
IQueryable<FooVm> result = foo
       .Between(start, end)
       .Select(f => new FooVm {
         FooId = f.Id,
         FooName = f.Name
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try using another variable instead of foo when selecting the FooVM result

```
foo2 = foo
    .Select(f => new FooVm {
         FooId = f.Id,
         FooName = f.Name
     });

return View (foo2);
```

in your first line, you "implicitly" using "var" declared foo to be `IQueriable<Foo>`, then in the end ur trying to assign it to a `IQueriable<FooVM>`

Comment: Yes. I've tried this and it works. But can't I use the same variable?